# Git difftool with missing file locally

Tags: git, git-difftool

I am using BeyondCompare to do merge, but I have an issue with not existing files locally.

On branch `dev` I have the file `src/foo.hpp`, but on `master` I don't have this file.

When I do :

```
git checkout master
git difftool dev
```

I cannot save my file, because it pointing to `/dev/null`.

Here my `.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "bc4"]
    cmd = "\"/mnt/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe\" \"$(wslpath -aw \"$LOCAL\")\" \"$(wslpath -aw \"$REMOTE\")\" /lefttitle=\"$(wslpath -aw \"$LOCAL\")\" /righttitle=\"$(wslpath -aw \"$REMOTE\")\""

[difftool "echo"]
    cmd = "echo" $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

If I do:

```
git difftool -techo dev 
/tmp/hxqHC9_foo.hpp /dev/null
```

I see that Git does not allow for creating file locally.

Is there a workaround other than this?:

```
touch src/foo.hpp
git add src/foo.hpp
git commit -m "Add missing file"
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the workarounds,

```
git checkout master

# Introduce the file from the branch "dev"
git checkout dev src/foo.hpp

git status
git commit
```

More generally, you can check out any file from any revision as long as the file exists in that revision,

```
git checkout $revision $path
```

If you want to copy a file of a revision to a new path without checking it out,

```
git show ${revision}:${path} > ${newpath}

# Or
git cat-file -p ${revision}:${path} > ${newpath}

# For example
git show dev:src/foo.hpp > src/bar.hpp
```